# What's the purpose of "torture dance" in Golden Wind?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

I've been following JoJo's Bizarre Adventure anime this season, it has 39 episodes total. It's currently on episode 11 (as of December 14, 2018).

I am confused with the dance that Narancia did with Fugo and Mista, while torturing Zucchero's head that got separated from his own body but was still alive, thanks to Bucciarati's Stand: *Sticky Fingers*.

What's the purpose of that dance and music towards Zucchero? When I listened to the music, it sounds like it's not a Japanese song, I didn't know what language they used. Does the dance have references from some sort of real life dance? Or is it just an original dance? Here is the scene when [Zucchero gets tortured](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQx_KMoCgJU).

Comment: I could be wrong but i guess it was more of a celebration dance, remember that Narancia was always playing music from his stereo during the trip, thats like his thing

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of the torture dance was a weird thing revolving around something special.

> If you look at the art that comes in the dance, it indicates Narancia's, Mista's, and Fugo's stands tormenting Mario Zucchero.

---

***Narancia Ghirga-Aerosmith***

**The art in the cut-scene indicates Aerosmith's bullets shooting towards him**

[image: AeroSmith]

---

***Mista Guido-Sex Pistols***

**The art represents a cross-hair on the eye which indicates Mista's accuracy with his stand**

[image: Sex Pistols]

---

***Pannacotta  Fugo-Purple Haze***

**The art seems to indicate Purple Haze's burning poison ability as he is burning Mario Zucchero**

[image: Purple Haze]

Comment: Coming back to this after a year, I think the commenter meant the movements themselves, and not the background clips that flash in between the movements.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly due to Araki's weird behavior in making stuff, he made the Torture Dance.
Most of the moves mimic Michael Jackson's dance moves, so it might be that.
Michael Jackson was alive in 1995 (the year Golden Wind came out), and Smooth Criminal was made before Golden Wind, so it could be inspired off MJ's style of dancing.